# Client_Side_Validation - Display position of validation "Password doesn't match confirmation"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, client-side-validation

I've tried client_side_validations gem for my validate form apps, that's working really great. I'm using Devise for my users model and when I go to the `new_user_registration` form, display validation "doesn't match confirmation" show on side of field password when I write password and change [tap tab] to field password confirmation.

look my app for sign up : [Example Devise](http://exampledevise.herokuapp.com/users/sign_up)

on model

```
validates_confirmation_of :password, :only => :create
validates_presence_of :password
```

How To Display position of validation  "doesn't match password" side of field password confirmation looks like ?

[image]

Comment: did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing my solution for this.

I hacked the code so that password_confirmation error is displayed correctly and only after the confirmation password is mistyped. Works with Zurb-Foundation form errors.

The file is located in app/assets/rails.validators.js

```
//= require rails.validations


window.ClientSideValidations.formBuilders['ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder'] = {
  add: function(element, settings, message) {
    var form = $(element[0].form);

    if (element.data('valid') !== false) {
      var for_id = element.attr('id');
      if (form.find("label.error[for='" + for_id + "']")[0] == null) {
        form.find("label[for='" +  for_id + "']").addClass('error');
        element.addClass('error');
        element.after('<small class="message error" for="' + for_id + '">' + message + '</small>');
      } 
    }

    return form.find("small.message[for='" + (element.attr('id')) + "']").text(message);
  },
  remove: function(element, settings) {
    var form = $(element[0].form);

    if (element.hasClass('error')) {
      var for_id = element.attr('id');
      form.find("label[for='" +  for_id + "']").removeClass('error');
      element.removeClass('error');
      form.find("small.error[for='" + for_id + "']").remove();
    }
    return element;
  }
}



window.ClientSideValidations.callbacks.element.fail = function(element, message, callback, event) {
  if (message.indexOf("doesn't match") != -1) {

    var eid = element.attr('id');
    var conf_el = $(element[0].form).find('#' + eid + '_confirmation');

    var form_id = $(element[0].form).attr('id');

    var settings = window.ClientSideValidations.forms[form_id];

    if (conf_el.data('interacted')) {
        ClientSideValidations.formBuilders[settings['type']].add(conf_el, settings, message);
    }
    ClientSideValidations.formBuilders[settings['type']].remove(element, settings);
    //callback();
  } else {
    callback();
  }
}


window.ClientSideValidations.callbacks.element.pass = function(element, callback, event) {
  var eid = element.attr('id');
  var conf_el = $(element[0].form).find('#' + eid + '_confirmation');

  if (conf_el.size() > 0) {
    var form_id = $(element[0].form).attr('id');
    var settings = window.ClientSideValidations.forms[form_id];
    //var settings = window.ClientSideValidations.forms['new_user'];
    ClientSideValidations.formBuilders[settings['type']].remove(conf_el, settings);
  } 

  callback();
}



$(function() {
  //bind change keyup keypress
  $("input[id$=_confirmation]").on('keyup keypress change', function(e) {
    $(this).data('interacted', true);
    $(this).off('keyup keypress change');
  });
});
```

Comment: can you specify, where have you made changes to exactly ? and will this work for  bootstrap ?